# Entity framework Code First and Fluent API have a difficulty with using type decimal?

Tags: c#, code-first, entity-framework-4.3, fluent-interface

I need help!

When I read a decimal value of the DB it returns a different value for C#.

For example: In DataBase the value is 0.0000 and in C# code the value read is 0.1200.

I need to know what is wrong not find anywhere.
Below follows the code:

C# Entity

```
public class Material
{
  public decimal SizeTub { get; set; }
}
```

C# Mappin

```
Property(e => e.SizeTub).HasColumnName("SIZE_TUB").HasPrecision(8, 4);
```

C# Pass Value

```
Material mat = new Material;
mat.SizeTub = 0.0000;
```

C# Repository Save

```
dbContext.Set<Material>().Add(mat);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

C# Repository Read

```
returnMat = dbContext.Set<Material>().ToList();
```

C# Return value

```
decimal sizeTub = returnMat[0].SizeTub; // sizeTub equals 0.12M
```

The value recorded is correct but when I read the value returns different from what was recorded.

Am I understood?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: What is the underlying database?  What happens when you save a value like 0.0001 to the database?

Comment: Is type of `returnMat` List<Material> ?

Comment: Are you saying that you are passing in 0.0000M and getting back 0.12M ?  Can you show the SQL that is getting sent to the database?

Comment: Are you sure you the only record in the table is the one you put there?  You are returning a list from the table and only reading the first record, which may not be the one you added.

Comment: I managed to solve!
I was mapping the wrong field! I changed the mapping and it worked!
I appreciate everyone's attention!